# Wierd text formatting in Java when manually compiling instead of using netbeans

Tags: java

At my university we regurly get programming assignments that (at least for now) usually deal with console programming. When I create my programs in Netbeans and compile and run from there, everything works as expected... However, when manually compiling using javac filename.java and running using java filename, i get wierd formatting errors when printing out lines... (System.out.println and System.out.printf)

Take this as an example. I'm printing out the contents of a table which when run in Netbeans looks like this:

```
Hybel Leietager      Saldo
--------------------------
1A    Ole Johan     6000
1B    Erik Smith    12000
1C    TOM HYBEL     0
1D    Alan Turen    9000
1E    Tim Verner    33000
1F    Anders Tanen  4999
2A    Torvald Linus 9000
2B    Rikard Stall  5001
2C    Bill Weitz    10000
2D    Steve Job     15000
2E    Steve Woz     123
2F    Denis Rich    2400
3A    James Goblin  88000
3B    Mark Sukker   456000
3C    Karl Bagasje  6000
3D    TOM HYBEL     0
3E    Ada Love      250
3F    Don Knut      55000

Periode: 9/2011
Total fortjeneste: 1400500
```

However, when manually compiling and running i get this:

```
Hybel Leietager      Saldo
--------------------------
    6000 Johan
   12000k Smith
    0TOM HYBEL
   9000an Turen
   33000 Verner
 4999Anders Tanen
9000 Torvald Linus
 5001Rikard Stall
   10000l Weitz
    15000e Job
    123eve Woz
   2400nis Rich
 88000ames Goblin
  456000k Sukker
 6000Karl Bagasje
    0TOM HYBEL
     250 Love
     55000nut

Periode: 9/2011
Total fortjeneste: 1400500
```

I don't understand, the function printing this out is a simple for-loop with System.out.println or printf... Anyone understand why this happens?

Here is the code, a bit difficult to understand as it's written in norwegian (i know, bad practise, it should all be english... but we're required to do it in the class, bad teachers, BAD!)

Basically, lengdenAvLengsteNavn() finds the longest name (listed under "Leietager"). genererOversiktTop() creates the header line, with required spacing (depending on the longest name). The header line is what reads "Hybel Leietager.....Saldo". horizontalSkille() prints out the horizontal devider ("--------...."), and hybelOversiktLinje() actually prints the line representing a hybel (condo) with correct spacing... As you can see, no tabs or /r's are used...

```
private void skrivOversikt () {
    System.out.println("*** Hybel Oversikt *** \n");
    String oversiktTop = genererOversiktTop();
    System.out.println(oversiktTop);
    System.out.println(horizontalSkille (oversiktTop.length()));

    for(int i = 0; i < etasjer.length; i++) {
        Etasje etasje = etasjer[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < etasje.hybler().length; j++) {
            Hybel hybel = etasje.hybler()[j];
            System.out.print(hybelOversiktsLinje (oversiktTop, hybel) + "\n");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Periode: " + innevaerendeMaaned + "/" + innevaerendeAar);
    System.out.println("Total fortjeneste: " + totalFortjeneste);
} //Skriver ut en oversikt over alle hybler, leietagere og deres saldo

private String genererOversiktTop () {
    String oversiktsTop = "Hybel Leietager";
    int leietagerSaldoSkille = lengdenAvLengsteNavn() - "Leietager".length();

    for (int i = 0; i < leietagerSaldoSkille; i++) {
        oversiktsTop += " ";
    }

    return oversiktsTop + " Saldo";
}

private String horizontalSkille (int lengde) {
    String skille = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < lengde; i++) {
        skille += "-";
    }

    return skille;
}

private String hybelOversiktsLinje (String oversiktsTop, Hybel hybel) {
    int leietagerIndex = oversiktsTop.indexOf("Leietager");
    int saldoIndex = oversiktsTop.indexOf("Saldo");
    String linje = hybel.romNavn();

    while (linje.length() < leietagerIndex) {
        linje += " ";
    }

    linje += hybel.leietagerNavn();

    while (linje.length() < saldoIndex) {
        linje += " ";
    }

    return linje + hybel.saldo();
}

private int lengdenAvLengsteNavn () {
    int lengsteLengde = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < etasjer.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < etasjer[i].hybler().length; j++) {
            Hybel hybel = etasjer[i].hybler()[j];

            if (hybel.leietagerNavn().length() > lengsteLengde)
                lengsteLengde = hybel.leietagerNavn().length();
        }
    }

    return lengsteLengde;
}
```

Comment: You should add your println and printf statements, so that we can see what went wrong. I suspect a wrong tab character used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `'\r'` character after the name. This character is interpreted differently on those two terminals.

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen maybe it's already included in `hybel.leietagerNavn()` string.

Answer (score 0):

Because the output consoles are different I guess. Each one handles special characters like tabulation in a different way.